# Windows Server 2003 Task Scheduler Fails to Kill Task Unless I'm Logged in

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I am having problems with a process started by a Windows task that is not being killed properly after it has run for a pre-determined amount of time even though the Windows task is created to kill the process after the amount of time has passed.
SchedLgU (the Windows Task Scheduler Log) says that the task started and ended on time, but the process continues even after the duration has passed.
However, when the task begins, and I am directly logged in to the machine, it ends normally. Why is this the case?

It is very similar to this [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/420706/task-scheduler-does-not-kill-task) except that the process and the machine are 32-bit.

Comment: What account is this task running as?  You?

Comment: Have you set the task to `Run only if logged in`?

Comment: @KatherineVillyard, the task is scheduled to run as my account.
Cole, the "Run only if logged in" box is unchecked.

Comment: I suspect that either it doesn't remember your password or your password was typoed when you entered it. It's hard to tell from the information provided, though.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard, the task does start when no one is logged onto the machine, but the problem is that the underlying process is not killed. I did not have to enter a password when I created the task.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard, I entered my password for the task, and it still does not stop the underlying process.

Comment: @Cole, the "Run only if logged in" box is unchecked.